# Selecting a value based on how another field was generated

Tags: mysql

I'm selecting some data;

```
select c.*,
coalesce(s.column1, ...),
coalesce(s.column2, ...),
FROM
    (SELECT ...)
```

Basically, if `s.column1` or `s.column2` is `null` then I am putting in some logic to take the average of that column and use it instead.

I want to have another field so I can know weather or not that value was computing using the average or not - perhaps a boolean? Lets say the average for column1 was 120, the table would look like;

```
column1    column2    avg
54         10         0
200        40         0
120        180        1
499        160        0
```

This allows me to see that the third row was generated using the `avg` of all rows as it was initially `null`.

How could the logic for the `avg` column work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems fairly moot to me because:

- The `AVG` function ignores `NULL` values by default, so the average using the overall average for `NULL` slots is the same as leaving out those slots entirely, and
- If you just want to mark the rows which had a `NULL` value, you can use a `CASE` expression

So, to get what you want, just use this:

```
SELECT
    column1,
    column2,
    CASE WHEN column1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS avg
FROM yourTable;
```

And know that `SELECT AVG(column1) FROM yourTable` would return the same value whether `NULL` rows were omitted, or the overall average were used.

Comment: The data is minutes. For example, each row in `s.column1` has a minute value. In some cases, it is `null`. I am taking the overall `avg` for the column and using that average minute in places where the data is missing. I.e. I need to backfill the data with something. I don't want to mark the column, I need a separate column so I don't lose the backfilled data.

Comment: @Someguywhocodes Maybe my point is not getting across.  If you're filling the missing values with the average of all the non `NULL` values, _then the average doesn't change_.  So, all you need then is a column(s) to keep track of the `NULL` values.

Comment: Ah, sorry - I mis interpreted. That makes perfect sense.